# Automation (SQL Query) to add Hard Bounces to a suppression list

Tags: marketing-cloud, query, sql

Is it possible to use the automation to update the actual suppression list? When I create the query, the Suppression list isn't available as an option.

I've looked at the answers to similar questions and they have been helpful, but there isn't anything about updating the actual suppression list: My Subscribers > Suppression Lists. Will I have to use a DE and just call it Suppression List?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you're doing something like a Contact Deletion where you want to ensure these bouncing email addresses don't find there way back into the account? If not, this operation is potentially redundant as Held subscribers are automatically suppressed from sends. Anyways,...

You cannot do this directly through the Automation Studio User Interface because the only way to get data into an Auto-Suppression List this way is through an Import Activity. Within the User Interface you would need to run several steps:

1. An SQL Query Activity identifying all those you want to suppress in your Auto-Suppression List
2. A Data Extension Extract Activity to generate a file containing the results of your Query Activity
3. A File Transfer Activity to push your new file from the Safehouse to your Enhanced FTP Server
4. An Import Activity to import your file from the Enhanced FTP directory to your Auto-Suppression List

This said, you can create a Query Activity using the SOAP API that you can then use in an Automation to run data directly into your Auto-Suppression List. Here is a sample SOAP Create Payload:

```xml
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:a="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
    <s:Header>
        <fueloauth>{{_token}}</fueloauth>
    </s:Header>
    <s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
        <CreateRequest xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
            <Options></Options>
            <Objects xsi:type="QueryDefinition">
                <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true"></PartnerKey>
                <ObjectID xsi:nil="true"></ObjectID>
                <CustomerKey>Overwrite Excluded Contacts ASL</CustomerKey>
                <Name>Overwrite Excluded Contacts ASL</Name>
                <Description>Places distinct excluded email address in Auto Suppression List</Description>
                <QueryText><![CDATA[SELECT DISTINCT
    EmailAddress AS [Email Address],
    GETDATE() AS [Date Added]
FROM
    _Subscribers
WHERE
    Status = 'held']]></QueryText>
                <TargetType>DE</TargetType>
                <DataExtensionTarget>
                    <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true"></PartnerKey>
                    <ObjectID xsi:nil="true"></ObjectID>
                    <CustomerKey>Excluded Contacts</CustomerKey>
                    <Name>Excluded Contacts</Name>
                </DataExtensionTarget>
                <TargetUpdateType>Overwrite</TargetUpdateType>
            </Objects>
        </CreateRequest>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Comment: Thank you for that information. I find it kind of strange that we have to create a "placeholder" DE and then move those people into the actual suppression list but it seems it's the only way. Thanks for the help.